# How to restore keyboard after deleting packages and a reboot

Tags: debian, configuration, keyboard

I made a terrible (and stupid) mistake. I ran an update operation, and   `aptitude` offered me alternatives that included deleting the `xserver-xorg*` packages. So I did so, thinking I'd reinstall them before I shutdown the computer, but I didn't.

So now I have a useless terminal session login screen because my TVE keyboard is not recognized. Is there anything I can do to restore my system to its original working state? Or do I have to reinstall it from scratch?

My operating system is (was?) Debian 64bit.

Comment: I don't know what a TVE keyboard is. Can you connect a USB keyboard while you reinstall the TVE driver?

Comment: Aptitude would not have suggested you delete packages on an update. So, were you trying to upgrade your system, or install some packages? And what release/version of Debian are you running? Additionally, consider using the `apt-get` or `apt` commands instead. They are more conservative about what packages they remove.

Comment: No, if your keyboard isn't working, there's nothing you can do. However, most keyboards just work. I don't know what a TVE keyboard is but, as a workaround, borrow or buy a cheap new keyboard and plug it in. Any USB keyboard will be recognized automatically.

Comment: You already tried boot CD/USB?

Answer (score 1):

You can boot without starting X (e.g. giving "single" to the boot command line in grub), then log in as root and install the needed packages.

Comment: Nope. The keyboard responds at grub línea edit screen, but it does not at "Vive robot password for maintenance" screen. That is the problema :(